# sorting SwiftyJSON results

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I'm using SwiftyJSON to populate a tableview which is working fine but I'm struggling to find a way of sorting the data. I've put my code as I have a feeling there's a better way of storing and displaying the data as at the moment I'm putting it into separate arrays per json tag which makes sorting difficult. Very new to swift so help is appreciated. Can I sort the json result before using it, or perhaps there's a better way of storing it?

I want to sort the below based on time to print to table view as at the moment it just prints in order.

Example json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "time": 13683
  },
  {
    "name": "Dave Smith",
    "time": 20683
  },
  {
    "name": "Craig David",
    "time": 200
  }
]
```

Current approach (no sorting):

```
// Global variables
var tableName = [String]()
var tableTime = [String]()

func getJSON(){
    // Removed all the code here to get the JSON 

    let json = JSON(data: result!)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        for item in json.arrayValue {
            if item["name"].stringValue != "" {
                self.tableName.append(item["name"].stringValue )
                self.tableTime.append(item["time"].stringValue)
            }
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    })
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableName.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!TableViewCell
        // Configure the cell...

        cell.name.text = tableName[indexPath.row]
        cell.time.text = tableTime[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom struct as data model

```
struct Data {
    var name : String
    var time : String
}
```

Then you have only one array to sort

```
// Global variables
var dataSource = [Data]()

func getJSON(){
    // Removed all the code here to get the JSON 

    let json = JSON(data: result!)
    for item in json.arrayValue {
        let name = item["name"].stringValue
        if !name.isEmpty {
            self.dataSource.append(Data(name:name, time:item["time"].stringValue))
        }
    }
    self.dataSource.sortInPlace{ $0.name < $1.name}
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!TableViewCell
        // Configure the cell...

        let data = dataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.name.text = data.name
        cell.time.text = data.time

        return cell

    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a much better way of storing them but it doesn't look like the sort is working for me. I've changed the sort from name to time and set time to Int in the struct and append but it's not sorting.

Comment: Sorry it looks as though I had messed something up, all working perfectly! many thanks.